# maps to numpy array, why is taking more time all together?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to optimize a loop on python. I'm trying to do it using map function, as you can see in the following code:

```
a=np.arange(5000)
z=map(lambda x: a[x]-1,range(5000))
j=np.array(list(z))
```

when I take the time of the code using %%timeit on the beginning of the code, It show me this number:

```
4.91 ms ± 71.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Now, when I take the time of each line, I obtain the following output:

```
6.66 µs ± 126 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
816 ns ± 5.11 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
1.34 ms ± 9.38 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Why the total time is different?

Comment: Is that code an example? What does your actual code look like?

Comment: is an example to show that the time is different

Comment: Is your actual code similar? By the way, there are like a million things which could lead to that difference in timings, particularly for such small numbers. I don't think you'll find anything definitive.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to measure timings of each line separately, `map` object returns empty iterator after the first evaluation. So that `j=np.array(list(z))` creates an array you supposed has been created just during the first execution and thereafter creates empty arrays. Using [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/profile.html) you can see how many times `lambda` was called:

```
import cProfile

a=np.arange(5000)
z=map(lambda x: a[x]-1,range(5000))

def f3():
    j=np.array(list(z))


cProfile.run('f3()')
         5005 function calls in 0.004 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     5000    0.003    0.000    0.003    0.000 <ipython-input-62-2cd7b69aa97e>:2(<lambda>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.004    0.004 <ipython-input-63-17354a2581c6>:1(f3)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.004 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.004 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {built-in method numpy.array}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}



cProfile.run('f3()')
         5 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <ipython-input-63-17354a2581c6>:1(f3)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method numpy.array}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```